# openssl x509 - what is trusted and rejected uses of SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl, openssl, x509

When using OpenSSL utils for signing .csr request, its possible to use "openssl ca" util and "openssl x509" util.

Openssl ca's text config file has all needed x509 options like keyUsage, extendedKeyUsage.

Openssl x509's command line has options -addtrust and -addreject. When you sign a certificate with those options, you can see them later in "openssl x509 -text" output, something like:

```
user@inet-pc:~$ openssl x509 -req -in test.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 1 -out test.crt -setalias "zzzz test alias" -addtrust emailProtection -addreject serverAuth
```

^ signing test.csr using own CA key and cert

```
user@inet-pc:~$ openssl x509 -text -in test.crt -nooutCertificate:
Data:
    Version: 1 (0x0)
    Serial Number: 1 (0x1)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
    Issuer: C=RU, ST=Some-State, O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, OU=sdds, CN=ca
    Validity
        Not Before: Apr 23 06:24:58 2013 GMT
        Not After : May 23 06:24:58 2013 GMT
    Subject: C=AU, ST=Some-State, O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, CN=test
    Subject Public Key Info:
    Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
    RSA Public Key: (2048 bit)
         Modulus (2048 bit):
        (huge text here)
    Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        (huge text here)
Trusted Uses:
  E-mail Protection
Rejected Uses:
  TLS Web Server Authentication
Alias: zzzz test alias
```

^ Trusted and Rejected uses. What are those uses for and how do they work? Why I cannot find any mention of them in [X509 RFC5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280)? How to use "openssl ca" to add same trusted/rejected uses? What about "clientAuth" usage? It isnt listed in "trusted" or "rejected" - will this certificate be trusted by most common applications?

Update 1: OpenSSL's x509 manual says that "trust" settings are valid for OpenSSL's "verify" util, but what is that util for? Can invalid "trust" settings cause verification fail by usual http browsers/etc?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the section 4.2.1.12 "Extended Key Usage" of the rfc5280 :

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.12

Edit:

You are right, I am afraid I read your question too quickly. The trust settings are an OpenSSL auxiliary information, which as far as I know is stil experimental. See :

https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/x509.html#TRUST_SETTINGS

Again, I am sorry for my previous answer.

Comment: I've looked into there, no words "trusted" or "rejected". It works the same way, if extended usage section is present - cert can only be used for specified purposes. !BUT! If you add that section and sign cert through "openssl ca", there will be no "trusted uses" or "rejected uses" fields added into final signed .crt.

Comment: Edit: "OpenSSL auxiliary information" means that information is only for OpenSSL or OpenSSL-compatible software and is never used by usual SSL/TLS compatible software => therefore can be easily ignored?

Comment: OpenSSL considers a CA with no trust auxiliary informations as fully trusted, and the information is ignored by software that do not understand it, so yes, it should be easily ignored. Note that "Trust settings currently are only used with a root CA".